# Why are my Office 365 homepage app icons monochrome?

Tags: office-365

Why is it that when I log into my company Office 365 homepage I get all apps in a monochrome, whereas when I log into my personal account I get colours? I think the usability of monochrome icons is very poor.

How do I change my company theme to also use colours? I had a look in the theme settings but couldn't see anything to fix this.

[image: Office 365 homepage app icons - monochrome]
versus
[image: Office 365 homepage app icons - with colours]